# Spring MVC maven project giving 404

Tags: java, spring, maven

Hi In my spring mvc webapp,request is not reaching toward controller,showing 404.Here is my tomcat log.
Not Being able to understand what exactly the issue is, as there are no compile time errors.I have gone through several other posts where the possible problem was java versioning issue,but I have checked that as well, my java version is 1.7 in pom.xml and in java compiler.I have done maven clean and build,still issue persists.

> WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}
>   Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:syllabusNew'
>   did not find a matching property.
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Server number:         8.0.28.0
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: OS Version:            6.1
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Architecture:          x86
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_02-b13
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\Syllabus Magt.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\Syllabus Magt.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\Syllabus Magt.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
>                   INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
>                   INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on
>   the java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_162/bin/client;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_162/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_162/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;C:\eclipse-jee-mars-2-win32\eclipse;;.
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>                   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:35 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
>                   INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:35 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
>                   INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:35 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
>                   INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:35 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>                   INFO: Initialization processed in 1112 ms
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
>                   INFO: Starting service Catalina
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:35 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
>                   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:41 AM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
>                   INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete
>   list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them.
>   Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and
>   JSP compilation time.
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>                   INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>                   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:41 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
>                   INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
>                   Mar 13, 2018 8:44:41 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>                   INFO: Server startup in 6044 ms

Here is dispatcher servlet.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- Specifying base package of the Components like Controller, Service,
        DAO -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.syllabus" />

    <!-- Getting Database properties -->
    <context:property-placeholder location="/resources/db.properties" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Specifying the Resource location to load JS, CSS, Images etc -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- View Resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- DataSource -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
        id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}"></property>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${database.user}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Hibernate SessionFactory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate-cfg.xml" />

        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.syllabus.entity"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction -->
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
</beans>
```

My web.xml

```
    <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>Servlet 3.0 Web Application</display-name>


    <display-name>My Project</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Controller:

```
package com.syllabus.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public ModelAndView showMessage() {
        System.out.println("in controller");

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("login");
        return mv;
    }


}
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<a href="login">Click here to login</a>
</body>
</html>
```

login.jsp:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
Welcome
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mapping is incorrect. You should put your code here. Controller Code and JSP and Config.

Comment: INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath ...  Check this is your app deployed correctly

Comment: I have checked that.There is no java versioning problem.